# What should I focus when migrating from a non-responsive reactjs website to responsive one

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, responsive

I have inherited a  non-responsive website that was created using reactjs. It is a fairly large website, that uses fixed layout. I have been tasked with evaluating/measuring the risks/effort of making the current website responsive. As i see it, these are the different things that I need to evaluate/accomplish that will help me with my goal

1. Go from fixed layout to relative layout. This might include using a grid layout or something similar
2. Decide on the app's flow, look and feel on mobile vs desktop. By this I mean, how should the links look when viewed in a mobile phone (maybe a hamburger menu) vs links that are laid out flat in a desktop browser.
3. What does it take to make individual components that make up the website responsive using media queries.

My question is should I prioritize one over another for whatever reason? And am I missing anything else that I should be focussing on

Thanks
K

Comment: It's possible this does not even affect `reactjs` but css only. This is a *very* broad question.

Comment: if one of the possible suggestions is to use something like react-responsive within my react components, doesnt that make this question reactjs related?

Comment: We don't know since we haven't seen the site and its source code. You have a very broad question about an unspecified site. The implementation framework is one of the least important things.

Comment: Am looking for anything that I have glaringly missed or overlooked, Wanting to hear from people who have gone through this, nothing else. If that comes across as too broad, am happy to delete this question